# URL management with Django, GraphQL, Apollo and VueJS

Tags: django, vue.js, graphql, vue-router, vue-apollo

As said in the title, I'm using `Django`, `GraphQL`, `Apollo` and `VueJS` in my project.
I'm developping it as a `SPA` (Single Page Application).

Everything works fine, until I hit the F5 button and refresh the page. Indeed, it shows an unknown page. The thing is it is `VueRouter` that is managing the SPA and it works fine. But when I press F5, that is `Django` that tries to serve a page for the current URL and since it doesn't know it, it can't serve the appropriate page.

I know I can set the VueRouter 'history' mode, which I did, and add a URL to Django that serves index.html whatever the URL is.

My problem is the following :
When I'm on a particular form view (i.e : a User form view) my URL is the following :

`http://localhost:8000/user`

Since I'm using GraphQL for my API, the retrieved data is not based on the URL. In fact, that is my VueJS component that says : `Hey Apollo, run that GraphQL to retrieve the User I want`.

So when I refresh, yes it serves the User form view..but empty.

The question is : How could I solve this ?

For clarification purposes, here are some code samples :

> My Django URLs :

```py
# (... other imports here ...)
from .schema import schema

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema))),  # 'schema' is the main GraphQL schema
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    re_path(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))  # I saw that many times to serve the page whatever the URL is when refreshing the page
]
```

> My Vue Router :

```js
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'MainApp' },
    // ...
    { path: '/users', name: 'UserList', component: UserList },
    { path: '/user/create', name: 'UserFormCreate', component: UserForm, props: true },
    { path: '/user', name: 'UserFormView', component: UserForm, props: true },
    { path: '/user/edit', name: 'UserFormEdit', component: UserForm, props: true },
    // Same pattern for other models like 'Group' ...
  ]
```

> My Example VueJS Component :

```js
<script>
import {
  // ...
  USER_QUERY,
  // ...
} from '../../graphql/base/user.js'

export default {
  name: 'UserForm',
  props: {
    userId: Number,
    editing: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    user: {
      query: USER_QUERY,
      variables () { return { id: this.userId } },
      skip () { return this.userId === undefined },
      result ({ data }) {
        this.form.username = data.user.username
        this.form.firstName = data.user.firstName
        this.form.lastName = data.user.lastName
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
      },
      // ...
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // ...
  }
```

I have to mention that I've seen more or less related topics but that doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your route paths to use params.  For example:

```
{ path: '/user/:userId', name: 'UserFormView', component: UserForm, props: true }
```

Now, the app will interpret any number following the `user/` path as a prop called `userId`.  (`props: true` is important here for using the params as props.)

The only other change you need to make is adjusting your router-links to include the `id` as well (Ex.:  http://localhost:8000/user/1) so that when the page is refreshed, there will be a param to read.

Comment: Since I already open the User form view from the list of them with 
```openUserFormView (user, index) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'UserFormView', params: { userId: user.id } })
    },
```
I guess it will instantly work ! Why didn't I think about it earlier...?!

Comment: Seems you had most of the needed design operational already, even `props: true` :)

Comment: Yes it seems.. But since I'm using GraphQL my mind was not thinking about doing it with parameters in the URL at all... I will try this and come back in case of problem ! Thanks

Comment: Well, it works perfectly. Everything was ready..the only thing I had to add is the `:userId` in the URL because everything else was already done. Thanks for your quick help, I wasn't thinking about doing it with params in URL right now..!